# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable // numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my function:

```
import numpy as np
def calc_mean():
    return np.loadtxt('GOOG.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=(6)).mean(axis=0)
```

Here is my `GOOG.csv`:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume     Adj Close # <-- column that I need
2013-09-27  874.82  877.52  871.31  876.39  1258800    876.39
2013-09-26  878.3   882.75  875     878.17  1259900    878.17
2013-09-25  886.55  886.55  875.6   877.23  1649000    877.23
2013-09-24  886.5   890.1   881.4   886.84  1467000    886.84
2013-09-23  896.15  901.59  885.2   886.5   1777400    886.5
2013-09-20  898.39  904.13  895.62  903.11  4345300    903.11
2013-09-19  905.99  905.99  895.4   898.39  1597900    898.39
2013-09-18  886.35  903.97  883.07  903.32  1934700    903.32
2013-09-17  887.41  888.39  881     886.11  1259400    886.11
2013-09-16  896.2   897     884.87  887.76  1336500    887.76
.............................................................
end of file:
.............................................................
2012-06-29  574.96  58013   572.20  580.07  2519500    580.07
2012-06-28  565.90  566.23  557.21  564.31  1920900    564.31
2012-06-27  567.70  573.99  566.02  569.30  1692300    569.30
2012-06-26  562.76  566.60  559.48  564.68  1350200    564.68
2012-06-25  567.33  568.09  557.35  560.70  1581600    560.70
```

When I run it, i have the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/misha/Documents/finance/finance.py", line 164, in <module>
  security_mean(file_list)
File "/home/misha/Documents/finance/finance.py", line 125, in security_mean
  return np.loadtxt('GOOG.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=(6)).mean(axis=0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 703, in loadtxt
  usecols = list(usecols)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix that?

if I change `usecols=(6)` on `usecols=(6,)` or `usecols=([6])` i have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/misha/Documents/finance/finance.py", line 164, in <module>
    security_mean(file_list)
  File "/home/misha/Documents/finance/finance.py", line 125, in security_mean
    return np.loadtxt('GOOG.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=([6])).mean(axis=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 825, in loadtxt
    vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks.

**NOTE:** all data in `GOOG.csv` are `strings`

Comment: Next time please post the *whole* traceback, not just the last line. If your code was much longer your typo would have been really hard to find without the traceback.

Comment: In the last traceback it's clear that you did *not* modify the code. The `(5)` is still there.

Comment: Do you have a blank line somewhere in your `GOOG.csv` file (perhaps at the end of the file)?

Comment: This new error means your GOOG.csv file doesn't have 6 columns....

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `usecols` argument should be an iterable:

```
usecols=(5,) # or [5]
```

Note that `(5)` is **not** a one-element tuple. It's simply equal to `5`. the `,`(comma) is what is important in building a tuple.

Comment: @MichaelVayvala As I commented on your question, if you do not post a traceback it's hard to understand what's happening. In fact I cannot reproduce your problem. Copying the sample data and using your code does **not** produce any `IndexError`. Please update the question with the code you are using now.

Comment: @MichaelVayvala I cannot reproduce the `IndexError`. In fact, if you want  to select the `Adj Close` column you should use `6` as column index(and it doesn't given an `IndexError`).

Comment: @Bakuriu-->> usecols : Which columns to read, with 0 being the first. For example, usecols = (1,4,5) will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns

Answer (score 1):

Using `(5)` does not create a tuple or iterable of any type.  You will have to use either `(5,)` or `[5]` in your `usecols` argument.